# Two years in Beta

Tags: discussion, site-activity

This is how we **enter our third year in beta**:

[image]

..while traffic in the last one and a half month shows an almost trigonometric regularity:

[image]

In my point of view, and given the peculiarities of the subject matter of this site, I would be ecstatic if the percentage of questions answered could stabilize at $80$%, and answers per question at $2$.

Another important datum from site Analytics : **Sources of Traffic**

[image]

The important news here is that **$91.2$% of all traffic is coming from search engines**. Now look back at the first printscreen, where at the bottom the SE team says:

> "Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic ***should*** come from search
>   engines."

(my emphasis). Well, we're there.

Comment: It seems stats are worsening, 7 months after this post. Visits and questions per day are much lower than before. Maybe in a month (for the 1000 days mark) you can give an update, to see if we can generate further critical mass on how to keep the site moving forward rather than backward.

Comment: @luchonacho You forget seasonality. The June 2017 was visibly higher in visits that June 2016 (while they were ~ the same regarding questions asked). I will indeed wait for the 1000-days mark to post more detailed data and analysis.